# to_formatted_s(:long_ordinal) returning 00:00 at the end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am using ActiveSupport's to_formatted_s.

Doing:

```
(User.first.birthday).to_formatted_s(:long_ordinal)
```

prints

```
 => "February 28th, 1992 00:00"
```

Why is there 00:00 at the end? Is this normal? What's the best way to get rid of it?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

:long_ordinal includes the time.

See activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/conversions.rb near the top of the file.

```
:long_ordinal => lambda { |time| 
  time.strftime("%B #{ActiveSupport::Inflector.ordinalize(time.day)}, %Y %H:%M") },
```

To get rid of it, define your own format like so:

```
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:my_long_ordinal] = lambda { |time| 
      time.strftime("%B #{ActiveSupport::Inflector.ordinalize(time.day)}, %Y") }
```

I put these sorts of things into config/initalizers/time_formats.rb like so:

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:month_year] = Time::DATE_FORMATS[:month_year] = "%B %Y"
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:mon_yr] = Time::DATE_FORMATS[:mon_yr] = "%b '%y"
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:yyyymmdd] = Time::DATE_FORMATS[:yyyymmdd] = "%Y-%m-%d"
```

Keeps them organized and in one spot.

Comment: Nice answer.  Plenty of web sites will tell you how to do things like define custom formats.  Few of them remember to tell you where to put it.

Comment: You could probably clean that up to be something like `{ :month_year => '%B %Y', ... }.each { |k, f| Date::DATE_FORMATS[k] = Time::DATE_FORMATS[k] = f }` to make it clear what the mappings are and avoid typos.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is normal, it is not just a date.

```
(User.first.birthday).to_date.to_formatted_s(:long_ordinal)
```